# If SSO (Single sign on ) is enabled for DocuSign, is there a way to integrate an application without using a password?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create a  envelope on DocuSign by integrating my application.

I know about the SOBO concept but due to some limitation, can't create a generic account.

So what i am asking here "Is it possible that with, only sender username + certified integration key info, the application can make an API call to create envelopes?"

One more thing, DocuSign production SSO is enabled for all the users I want. So is there a way that I can get any help from SSO?

Any help around this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote all useful answers, including answers to others' questions. And select/check the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the new DocuSign OAuth support to enable your app's users to authorize your app to make API calls on their behalf.

[DocuSign OAuth docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#DocuSignOAuth/docusign-oauth.htm)

Some notes about this:

1. Each of your users will need to authorize your app to make API calls on their behalf.
2. There are different ways to set up the OAuth capability depending on whether your app is a local/mobile app or a server-based app. The latter can protect its client secret, the former can't. Both are supported. See the docs for more info.
3. The new OAuth capability is not yet available for a "system account" that autonomously makes API calls on its own behalf (this doesn't apply to your question.)

Also, you say there is "some limitation" preventing you from setting up a generic (system) account to use the API on behalf of the account holders (this is the SOBO use case). I suggest that you push a little on the "limitation." Trying to get 10 or 10,000 individuals to separately authorize an app to act on their behalf is not easy. The goal of SOBO is to make it easy for authorized system apps to send on behalf of others.

Comment: Thanks larry for replying ,i just want to know one thing that the redirect uri can be added if  the key is already registered and what redirect uri i should use  :As redirect uri : determines where to redirect the user after they successfully authenticate. Can i use this as redirect Uri:https://www.docusign.com/devcenter ?.

Comment: got that the redirect-uri should be the end point of my application ,so only one question left that "can we add the redirect uri after registering the integrator key "? or it can be added only before registration?

Comment: You can edit/update the redirect uri whenever you wish. Choose the "Edit" action for the integration key.

Comment: If the redirect uri contains parameter in it for eg if redirect_uri="http://appsserver:portnumber/taskspace/component/main/?appname=XYZ " then how to pass the parameters.I tried with converting the parameter to json format and then encoding it and then passing the encoded string  to  state variable in get request , it doesnt work ,is that the right approach ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't yet written an OAuth app for the platform. I suggest that you try your proposal, then ask a new question here on stack overflow if you have questions or problems.