# Can you use an API account and Legacy Authentication for SOBO when the organization's users have SSO enabled?

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, docusignapi

While SSO is enabled for an organization, can an API account still use Legacy Authentication ([username/password still being used for this account](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-exclude-specific-users-from-SSO-requirements)) on behalf of a user that has SSO enabled?

Our company wants to transition to using SSO for all user accounts (except possibly the API account). Currently, we use DocuSign's Legacy Authentication header (X-DocuSign-Authentication) to send envelopes on behalf of users and create sender views for them. Both of these actions involve using our API account's username and password for authentication on behalf of a user.

I've read [this](http://%20X-DocuSign-Authentication) post that says:

> If you're using Legacy Header authentication, your application won't
> be able to authenticate as users who have SSO Login enforced. Until
> you're able to implement one of the OAuth workflows, users who need to
> use your API integration will need to have their Login Policy set to
> allow them to login with a password.

Does this mean that any user account that will be sent on behalf of them will need to have SSO disabled while the Legacy Authentication header (and API account using username/password) is being used?

In addition, we are trying to avoid having *every* user separately authorize the application to act on their behalf. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205258/4413616) post seems to mention there is a way to avoid that. Both the Authorization Code Grant and JWT Grant state that you must get your user's consent. We want to avoid this since we have 100's of members and staff additional staff added frequently.

Optimally, we would like to keep the API things as they are. If we can't or shouldn't, what changes do we have to make?

Answer (score 1):

If SSO is *enabled*, a user can still authenticate via their DocuSign password, and thus Legacy Header auth will still work. If SSO Authentication is *made mandatory* via Login Policy settings, the user cannot authenticate with their DocuSign password, and Legacy Header auth will break.

If your authenticating "system sender" user has SSO optional, the SendOnBehalfOf header can be used to impersonate anyone on the account, regardless of the other user's Login Policy settings.

If you have a Claimed Domain, you can grant Admin consent so that all users with email addresses under that claimed domain (current and future) will not be required to grant individual consent for JWT impersonation. More information on that is available here: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent